# Want to access JSP Variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, menu

This is for creating dynamic menu. So, I'm processing the data from DB in JSP and I have to send it to menu.js in order to create it dynamically. How can I pass it.??
One more thing.. I'm including my menu.js in that JSP file.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your work. Just by asking the question is not going to help.

Comment: What is the type of jsp variable?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use JSTL tag for accessing the JSP variable in JavaScript for example here is code snippet. Where **seatList** is your JSP variable.

```js
<script>
var list = [];
 <c:forEach items="${seatList}" var="seat">
 var arr = [];
 arr.push("<c:out value="${seat.seatNo}" />");
 list.push(arr);
 </c:forEach>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to share the variable:

- Sharing value by hidden fields, later access the value with `menu.js`.
- Declare a global js variable in jsp
  `<script>` and later access it in your `menu.js`
- Pass as argument to a function declared in `menu.js`.
- Using `localStorage` to share the value.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do so. If you are fine with scriplets then here is the code. you can do the same with other approaches.
write below code in your jsp.

```
<script>
var jsVariable='<%=jspVariable%>';
</script>
```

now you can access this jsVariable in your menu.js
You can write `<c:out>` instead of scriplet as well.